# How could I optimize this code? I need to do it in all 50 states, and in each state the text changes

Tags: javascript, php, html

How could I optimize this code? I need to do it in all 50 states, and in each state the text changes so I would like to know if there is another way than adding fifty ifs conditions

What I want to do is add dynamic text in each state which are 50 and in each of them there is different information, this is being developed in wordpress

if there is some other way to make it more optimal or better practice, maybe using jqueryde. thanks

```
<select onchange="states_info(this.value)" name="country" id="country">
    <option value="Alabama" selected><?php echo "Alabama"?></option>
    <option value="Alaska"><?php echo "Alaska" ?></option>
    <option value="Arizona"><?php echo "Arizona" ?></option>
    <option value="Wisconsin"><?php echo "Wisconsin" ?></option>
</select>
<h2 id="Title" ><?php echo "Alabama Requirements"?></h2>
<p id="credits" ><?php echo "Total Credits: 12 "?></p>
<ul>
    <li id="li_1" ><?php echo "At least 1 in Ethics"?></li>
    <li id="li_2" ><?php echo "At least 6 Live"?></li>
    <li id="li_3" class="hide"></li>
</ul>
<p id ="change_due" class="b" ></p>
<p id="Deadline"><?php echo " Deadline: December 31st"?></p>
<p id="change" class="b"></p>
<p id="reported" ><?php echo "How are credits reported?"?></p>
<button id="webinars"  class="button-custom"></button>
<button id="ethics"    class="button-custom"></button>

<style>
    p.b{
        font-style: italic;
        display:none; 
        color: blue;
    }
    .hide{
        display:none;  
    }
    .thick {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .normal {
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    .button-custom{
        background-color: Transparent;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        border-color: #5CCAF3;
        color: #5CCAF3;
        border-radius:5px;
        cursor:pointer;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        display:none;
        height: 45px;
    }
</style>

<script>
    function states_info(state){
        if(state =="Alabama"){
            document.getElementById("Title").innerHTML = "Alabama  Requirements";
            document.getElementById("credits").innerHTML = "Total Credits: 12 credit hours every year";
            document.getElementById("li_1").style.display = "block";
            var normal = document.getElementById("li_1");
            normal.classList.remove('thick');
            normal.classList.add("normal");
            document.getElementById("li_1").innerHTML = "• At least 1 in Ethics";
            document.getElementById("li_2").style.display = "block";
            var bold = document.getElementById("li_2");
            bold.classList.remove('thick');
            bold.classList.add("normal");
            document.getElementById("li_2").innerHTML = "• At least 6 Live";
            document.getElementById("Deadline").innerHTML = " Deadline: December 31st";
            document.getElementById("change").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("reported").innerHTML = "How are credits reported?  Alabama .";
            document.getElementById("webinars").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("ethics").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("change_due").style.display = "none";
        }
        if(state == "Wisconsin"){ 
            document.getElementById("Title").innerHTML = "Wisconsin Requirements";
            document.getElementById("credits").innerHTML = "Total Credits: 30 credit hours every 2 years.";
            document.getElementById("li_1").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("li_1").innerHTML = "• At least 3 in Ethics ";
            document.getElementById("li_2").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("change_due").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("change_due").innerHTML = "*Change due";
            document.getElementById("Deadline").innerHTML = "Deadline: December 31st";
            document.getElementById("change").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("reported").innerHTML = "How are credits reported? Wisconsin ";
            document.getElementById("webinars").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("webinars").innerHTML = "Live webinars for Wisconsin";
            document.getElementById("ethics").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("ethics").innerHTML = "Live ethics webinars for Wisconsin";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `jquery` if you're using plain JS?

Comment: @Ricardo Garcia 
array is the best way to go if you have multiple different text box for different states.

Comment: in your case of 50 states it is better to use ajax call to some php function to retrieve states info and then just swap it in browser, instead of so many operations with DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an object that contains the information about each state:

```
const state_data = {
    Alabama: {
        credits: "Total Credits: 12 credit hours every year",
        Deadline: "December 31st",
        change_due: null,
        li_1: "• At least 1 in Ethics",
        li_2: "• At least 6 Live",
        reported: "How are credits reported?  Alabama .",
        change: null,
        webinars: null,
        ethics: null
    },
    Wisconsin: {
        credits: "Total Credits: 30 credit hours every 2 years.",
        deadline: "December 31st",
        change_due: "*Change due",
        li_1: "• At least 3 in Ethics",
        li_2: null,
        reported: "How are credits reported?  Wisconsin .",
        change: null,
        webinars: "Live webinars for Wisconsin",
        ethics: "Live ethics webinars for Wisconsin"
    },
    ...
};
    

function states_info(state) {
    document.getElementById("Title").innerHTML = `${state} Requirements`;
    Object.entries(state_data[state]).forEach((id, value) => {
        let el = document.getElementById(id);
        if (value !== null) {
            el.style.display = "block";
            el.innerHTML = value;
        } else {
            el.style.display = "none";
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks, it's my first project, thanks for that solution